# Responsive and fixed together

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am looking to have a list which is 100% wide. However the start of each list item will be a set width wide.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><span>This</span> One</li>
        <li><span>This</span> Two</li>
        <li><span>This</span> Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I assume you'll be posting your CSS shortly?

Comment: Trying to put together a quick jsfiddle

Comment: you can do it with CSS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand the question correctly you can just set the ul to

```
display:block; width:100%;
```

and you elements to however large you want them

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/t2VFe/

let me know if you meant something different and I can answer :)

Comment: Nearly that. Changed the span to be the 300 width, and looking the one, two, three to span the rest of ul which is 100% http://jsfiddle.net/t2VFe/2/

Comment: What else needs to be done?

Comment: See on my edit there I am looking the one, two and three inline just after the white spaned background

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/t2VFe/5/

Comment: Yes thats it thank you. Im working with a theme but cant get it just working ok with it but il work with it see how it goes, thank you

Comment: no worries! Take a look at w3schools display properties for further reference, you may also want to check out floating elements too. It would be useful for structure

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that the first list item is fixed, but the rest should be responsive? Please clarify.

The CSS only solution I know of is the css `calc` method. Let's say you have four items in total and your first item is 200px wide, you would do it like this:

```
ul > li {
    width: 25%; /* Fall back */
    width: -webkit-calc((100% - 200px) / 3);
    width: -moz-calc((100% - 200px) / 3);
    width: calc((100% - 200px) / 3);
}
ul > li:first-child {width: 200px;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2VFe/4/) (adapted from Shalom Aptekar).

Note: not all browsers support this method. See [here](http://caniuse.com/calc).

Comment: Sorry no its not the li that needs the set width its the content within it, http://jsfiddle.net/t2VFe/6/ the span within the li is the set width and the rest of it is the width of the ul